# How to convert a github repository to local project component code?

Tags: github, npm

There is a github repository that is no longer actively maintained. I want to use the code and move it into my project's components but that is tedious and not sure if that is the best approach.
I just want to bump the version of draftjs used by the repository.

Here is the repo and it uses `draft js version 0.10.0`

https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft

My local project uses `draft js version 0.11.7`

This causes errors and incompatibility issues.

What is the best approach when a repository uses an outdated version of a repository used by local project?

Answer (score 0):

Before forking and publishing to npm your own version of that dependencies, you might consider using the [`package/patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

> Patches created by patch-package are automatically and gracefully applied when you use npm(>=5) or yarn.
>
> No more waiting around for pull requests to be merged and published. No more forking repos just to fix that one tiny thing preventing your app from working.

```sh
# fix a bug in one of your dependencies 
vim node_modules/some-package/brokenFile.js
 
# run patch-package to create a .patch file 
npx patch-package some-package
 
# commit the patch file to share the fix with your team 
git add patches/some-package+3.14.15.patch
git commit -m "fix brokenFile.js in some-package"
```

In your case, you would be patching the [`brijeshb42/medium-draft/package.json`](https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft/blob/c5350bb76489fd4f2f90f1dc69db92224138d20a/package.json#L32) file.